# Composer fails [UnexpectedValueException]

Tags: magento, composer-php, magento2

After installing a new version of a Magento 2 module composer fails on every command. Also the backend of Magento isn't working anymore:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (UnexpectedValueException): Package magento/composer's 
source key should be specified as {"type": ..., "url": ..., 
"reference": ...},
{"type":"git","url":"https:\/\/github.com\/magento\/composer.git","reference":null} given.
```

Also when using `composer -v` command via ssh the same error is showing.

When trying to flush the cache via ssh the same error is showing and also an extra error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Cli' not found in
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Few things you can try:
Try to reinstall composer. 
Also you can try running `composer clear-cache`. Also check for any running composer process and kill then first.

Answer (score 0):

If this is still an issue anyone has I found through much digging that reference cannot be set to null. If a download from source is necessary than I recommend moving up a directory for your url or use a dist instead of source